# Determine BIG-O Complexity for algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

The solutions of one of my homework assignments was posted up just now and I gota question wrong. It is pertaining to finding the worst case number of times an algorithms performs a multiplication operation (T(n)).

```
function power2n(n)
  counter = n
  product = 1
  while (counter > 0) {
    product = product * n * n
    counter = counter - 1
  }
  return product
```

According to my teacher, the worst case is 2n, but I don't understand why..

Comment: It seems a bit pedantic to say this is O(2N) and not O(N)

Comment: I think the teacher was being specific about 2n, not O(2n). In practice, a 2x increase in speed is nothing to sneeze at, and the number of multiplications this function performs can be greatly reduced. Note that `n*n` is independent of counter, and can be precomputed.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: Not only pedantic, but *wrong*. We *never* keep the constant multipliers in Big-O notation. Even if it's a million.

Answer (score 3):

Watch the variable `counter`. How does it change? It is initially `n`, and then it decrements by 1 for each iteration of the loop, so we know the loop will execute exactly `n` times.

Now, how many multiplications are performed?

We know for certain that there are 2 multiplications per loop (n*n*product).

So overall there will be n*(2) = 2n multiplications performed. In Big O notation this remains O(n)

Comment: Pedantic point: as @chepner points out, `n * n` can be precomputed.  The compiler may spot this and hence only perform n multiplications.

Comment: Good point, @Stefan. That's definitely possible. Fortunately that doesn't change the complexity, so I'll leave the post as-is.